# Check for pattern match with UUIDv4 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, uuid

I am looking for a pattern match with certain string before and after the uuid.

e.g.`user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256/photo/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256`

```
const regexExp = new RegExp(/^user\/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[4][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i);

console.log(regexExp.test("user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256")); // true

console.log(regexExp.test("user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256/photo")); // false
```

What I am expecting is to match `user/{uuid}/*` How to use a wildcard after the uuid?

Comment: You can omit the anchors and you don't need the RegExp constructor like `const regexExp = /user\/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[4][0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}(?:\/.*)?/i;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match both, you can omit using the RegExp constructor as you are already using a literal and optionally match `/` followed by the rest of the string.

The `[4]` can be just `4`

```
const regexExp = /^user\/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}(?:\/.*)?$/i;
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNDErB/1).

```js
const regexExp = /^user\/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}(?:\/.*)?$/i;

[
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256",
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256/photo",
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256asdasd"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regexExp.test(s)}`)
);
```

Comment: In this case `user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256asdasd` with incorrect uuid is considered a match. This should return false.

Answer (score 0):

The popular [uuidjs/uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) project provides a `uuid.validate()` function that uses the [following REGEX](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/main/src/regex.js#L1C16-L1C134) for UUID validation

```
/^(?:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)$/i
```

I'd recommend using this Regex as the basis of your solution.

After adding your custom requirements for `user/$UUID/*`  and removing `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` you get the following:

```
/^user\/([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})(?:\/.*)?$/i
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNDErB/1).

```js
const regexExp = /^user\/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}(?:\/.*)?$/i;

[
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256",
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256/photo",
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256/",
  "user/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "user/a24a6ea4-ce75-4665-a070-57453082c256asdasd",
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regexExp.test(s)}`)
);
```